# Easy dynamic programming recursive formula (uva 147 coin change)

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, acm-java-libraries

the problem is about coin change - "how many ways you can change 3,5,10 dollars 
if you have 5c,10c ......

"http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=83

the problem is solved many times on various blogs( solution  [here](http://jijingshanlin.blogspot.ca/2012/07/147-dollars.html) )

**In dp, the hardest thing is to understand the relation between subproblems and get the formula(optimal substructure)**

I only give the actual for loop that stores the ways into 2d table like the solution:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= NCHANGES; ++i){
for (int m = 1; m <= MAX_AMOUNT; ++m){
  if (m >= coins[i])
    n[i][m] = n[i-1][m] + n[i][m - coins[i]];
  else
    n[i][m] = n[i-1][m];
}
```

}

=================================

The actual important code:

```
  if (m >= coins[i])
        n[i][m] = n[i-1][m] + n[i][m - coins[i]];
      else
        n[i][m] = n[i-1][m];
```

My thinking.

for example: 
(else case)

- **I have the amount 5 cents and 1 coin to use : 5c.   there is only 1 way : 5c = 1 * 5c
  (store n[5][coin(5)])**
- **I have the amount 5c and 2 coins to use : 5c and 10c**  **i can't use BOTH 5C and 10c => i go back to 1 WAY of doing  it ( store 1 in the table for n[5][coin(5,10)])
  for this case**

that's why n[i][m] = n[i-1][m]

can you explain the first if case?  **n[i][m] = n[i-1][m] + n[i][m - coins[i]]**?

Comment: why no one looking at this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found it on a website - same problem.

The coin change recurrence:
a[i][j] = a[i-1][j] (d[i] > j)
(If the coin can't be used, then don't use it)

a[i][j] = a[i-1][j] + a[i][j-d[i]] (d[i] <= j)
**(If the coin can be used:  don't use OR use it)**